# TestCase for UIPOPOverViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, testcase, ocmock

For IPAD APP
I have a bar button item with a "Plus" icon as background.
when i click on it i display a UIPopOverViewController.
I want to write a test case to check that the PopOver is displayed when plus button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the popover in your view, you can make a partial mock of it and then verify that the present method is called. It would look something like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
id popoverMock = OCMPartialMock(vc.popover);
[vc pressPlusButton];
OCMVerify([popoverMock presentPopoverFromRect:OOCMOCK_ANY inView:OCMOCK_ANY permittedArrowDirections:OCMOCK_ANY animated:OCMOCK_ANY]);
```

If you don't have and/or don't want a reference to the popover, you'll probably have to make a class mock of `UIPopOverViewController`, stub its `initWithContentViewController:` to return the class mock, and then you can verify that present was called in a similar fashion as above.

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
id popoverMock = OCMClassMock(UIPopOverViewController);
OCMStub([popoverMock initWithContentViewController:OCMOCK_ANY]).andReturn(popoverMock);
[vc pressPlusButton];
OCMVerify([popoverMock presentPopoverFromRect:OOCMOCK_ANY inView:OCMOCK_ANY permittedArrowDirections:OCMOCK_ANY animated:OCMOCK_ANY]);
```